# Bot not changing status In discord.py I got no errors

Tags: python, bots, discord.py, status

I am not able to change the status. I want to develop my own bot and have to add more features too

```
# Importing Modules
import discord
import asyncio
import random
import DateTime
from discord.ext import commands
from urllib import parse, request
import re
import time

# Importants
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='*', description="This is a Helper Bot")
client = discord.Client()


# ***ADDING FEATURES***

# Getting Online And Changing status

async def my_background_task():
    await client.wait_until_ready()

    # Setting `Playing ` status
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name="With Your Life"))
    time.sleep(5)
    # Setting `Streaming ` status
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Streaming(name="Kartik Jain", url="https://youtube.com/c/KartikJainChannel"))
    time.sleep(5)
    # Setting `Listening ` status
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.listening, name="To *help"))
    time.sleep(5)
    # Setting `Watching ` status
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name=" Your Nonsense"))
    time.sleep(5)

# While Loop To loop changing statuses
while not bot.is_closed():
    bot.bg_task = bot.loop.create_task(my_background_task())

# Making the bot online
client.run('My_ID')
```

Comment: use `await asyncio.sleep(5)` instead of `time.sleep(5)` it's blocking your code, also take a look at [discord.ext.tasks](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html?highlight=tasks)

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the `bot` with `client` and you have to change this `my_background_task()` to this: `on_ready()`.

Just look at this code:

````
import discord
import asyncio
import random
import DateTime
from discord.ext import commands
from urllib import parse, request
import re
import time

# Importants
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='*', description="This is a Helper Bot")
client = discord.Client()


# ***ADDING FEATURES***

# Getting Online And Changing status

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Streaming(name="My live",url="http://www.twitch.tv/G4merStop"))
    time.sleep(5)
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Streaming(name="Your live",url="http://www.twitch.tv/G4merStop"))
    time.sleep(5)
    # ^^^^ here you can see what you can do in the docs ^^^^

# Making the bot online
client.run('My_ID')```
````

Comment: `time.sleep(5)` blocks the code, use `await asyncio.sleep(5)` instead

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński Yes

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you're actually creating 2 different instances of the client, `client` using `discord.Client` and `bot` using `commands.Bot`. You're using `bot` to change the presence, and in the end, you're running the `client` instance, which makes part done using `bot` totally useless.

You don't need to use `discord.Client`, because `commands.Bot` has all the methods and attributes of `discord.Client`.

Next, you should change `time.sleep()` to `await asyncio.sleep()` because it's blocking your code and also put the `bot.loop.create_task()` method inside `on_ready` event